# jQuery selector - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following Html:

```
<td>
    <div class="preWorkHoursCell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="timelineCell" data-resourceid="@(resource.Id)" data-date="@(currentDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="postWorkHoursCell">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
function createEvent(resourceId, startDate) {
    var timelineCell = $(".timelineCell[data-resourceid=" + resourceId + "][data-date=" + startDate + "]");
    console.log(timelineCell.length);  // <-- This is 1

    var preWorkHoursCell = $(timelineCell).closest(".preWorkHoursCell");
    console.log(preWorkHoursCell.length);    // <-- This is 0
}
```

How do I get a reference to the preWorkHoursCell div given the timelineCell?

Comment: Given timelineCell you get to preWorkHoursCell using prev() - http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/),

Use

```
var preWorkHoursCell = $(timelineCell).prev(".preWorkHoursCell");
```

OR

```
var preWorkHoursCell = $(timelineCell).closest('td').find(".preWorkHoursCell");
```

Comment: .prev worked great!  I figured out that you can also use .sibling.